# R t.test() with data.frames as arguments

Tags: r, syntax, t-test

There is a question on CrossValidated, where someone gave two dataframes instead of two vectors to the `t.test` function: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261830/t-test-or-wilcox-in-r-and-how-to-apply-to-dataframe-splitted-in-2-groups/

See this code for a shorter example

```
a <- data.frame(foo=1:5, bar=5:9)
b <- data.frame(foo=1:5, bar=5:9)
t.test(a,b)
```

The `help` page for the `t.test` function clearly states that x and y should be

> a (non-empty) numeric vector of data values.

Still the above code throws no error but gives a result. What is the meaning of the result?

Comment: I would suspect `a` and `b` are being coerced to vectors and that's what's being tested. Compare your result with `t.test(as.vector(as.matrix(a)), as.vector(as.matrix(b)))`. By the way, I receive no error with your code.

Comment: Yes, that produces an identical result. Weird that data frames are coerced like that, though. How can that behavior be useful?

Comment: In my personal opinion, this should definitely throw an error or at least a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is undocumented behavior, but you go against documentation when passing data.frames.

This happens:

```
x <- a
y <- b
yok <- !is.na(y)
xok <- !is.na(x)
y <- y[yok]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9
x <- x[yok]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9
```

Basically, you get the same result as if you did `t.test(unlist(a), unlist(b))`.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at the code inside :

```
 stats:::t.test.default
```

I showned here some selected pieces of code

```
function (x, y = NULL, alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"), 
    mu = 0, paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, 
    ...) 
{
    alternative <- match.arg(alternative)
    if (!missing(mu) && (length(mu) != 1 || is.na(mu))) 
    ### snip
    if (!is.null(y)) {
    ### snip
       yok <- !is.na(y)
       xok <- !is.na(x)
    ### snip
      y <- y[yok]
```

So we do have a y argument and you will see that `yok` will lead to a selection that will  be turned into a vector when used in `y[yok]`. Finally everything will happens on data.frame coerced to vectors (`as.vector`).

Definitively not what one would intend to do but also miss-specifications from user...

Comment: Yes, that misspecification would have gone unnoticed, if (s)he had not tried to do a `wilcox.test` as well.